# How can I output the Debug Sampler's output to the JMeter log?

Tags: jmeter

I have several JMeter variables that are read in from User-Defined Properties, read from a CSV, or extracted from an HTTP response.

I need to be able to output the variables in a log file, and want to include them in the jmeter.log for now. I know how to use the Debug Sampler to view them in the JMeter UI, but it does not seem that they are being saved to jmeter.log.

Is it possible to configure JMeter to log the output of the Debug Sampler in jmeter.log, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using an appropriate [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and simple [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) script like:

```
vars.entrySet().each { var -> log.info(var.key + '=' + var.value) }
```

Demo:

[image]

Where:

- `vars` - stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
- `log` - is [Log4JLogger](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.html)

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)